# Faster insertion into two related tables

Tags: sql-server, database, auto-increment, sql-insert

I have devices which continually sends some data, and I'm saving it to the database. I'm searching for fast way of doing it. Now the data are sent to msmq and then I'm doing multiple inserts, but it takes too long. I'm waiting for the Data record to be inserted, getting the ID, and then I'm inserting related records in DataAttachment. The schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Data](
  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [IDDevice] [int] NOT NULL,
  [Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [Value] [varchar](20) NOT NULL, 
...
```

)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataAttachment](
  [IDData] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [AttachmentType] [int] NOT NULL,
  [FileName] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [FileContent] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
```

)

I was thinking of preparing multiple inserts where I'd get last inserted id after each inserted Data, and use it to insert attachments. But I think that it is not a good idea, if there have been insertion to another table, I'd get wrong ID.

Another option would be generating a hash from Time and Value which could be inserted in DataAttachment and Data. Then it would be possible to insert multiple data in Data and DataAttachment without problems and then I'd just change IDData in DataAttachment by searching for the Data by hash value.

I'd like to ask for an advice how to do the insertion fast.

Comment: You can syncronize data from the device itself. Add new column in which will be the syncronization of IDs between `Data` and `Attachment`. For fater insert you can use 2 temp tables. You can try to use BULK insert (although I don't know if you can use it on your devices). After that using a validation procedure you can insert quick into your main table.

Comment: Insert row by row is very slow process. You must try to use set based approach (native for SQL databases). Add more details about devices that you are working with - type, OS, etc.

Comment: You need a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario is a perfect case for using a Sequence object (SQLServer 2012 and later). I know because I have used it for exactly what you're trying to do - right down to the table names and DDL being very similar.

A sequence object allows you to create unique IDs to be used for the ID column of the dbo.Data table and the related IDData (foreign key) column in your dbo.DataAttachment table. It avoids waiting on a dbo.Data insert to happen before inserting the related attachments into dbo.DataAttachment. It lets you avoid using GUIDS and their related problems. And it allows for easily batching inserts to speed performance.

Here's a great link on Sequence objects:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

A basic approach would be to create a sproc that:

1. Looks for all new Data records to be inserted (guessing from one of your msmq tables) and then inserts them to a temp table. On the temp table, you should have an ID column that grabs the NEXT VALUE FOR [your_sequence_object]. That ID will be the primary key for the new Data row to be inserted. You'll need to disable the Identity property on this column in your Data table.
2. Next, create another temp table that will hold your related attachments for each of the data rows. When creating this temp table, you'll be joining between the Data temp table created in step 1 above and whatever sources you're retrieving the DataAttachment rows from. This will let you use the ID column in your step 1 Data temp table for the foreign key column IDData in DataAttachment.

As for the ID column of the DataAttachment table (your primary key on this table), you can leave it as is with the Identity property left on, in which case you would leave it out of the DataAttachment temp table and not explicitly insert it. Or, you could use a different sequence object to generate the unique values for it.

3. Insert the contents of the Data temp table into the dbo.Data table, and then insert the contents of the DataAttachment temp table into the dbo.DataAttachment table.

Answer (score 0):

You need a foreign key for this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataAttachment](
  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [IDData] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Data(ID),
  [AttachmentType] [int] NOT NULL,
  [FileName] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [FileContent] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
)
```

You rightly note that you can't create the foreign key until you know the ID.

You have two options.

One is to use a data type for the ID (unique key) which can be chosen on the client side. To do this you need a way for the client to generate a unique id which will not conflict with the (unknown) values already stored on the server.

The typical way to do this is to use `uniqueidentifier` (a GUID) which is designed for this purpose. Then you can allocate them on the client side, so you know ahead of time that they are unique. An alternative would be to use a random 64-bit integer (this is what Oracle uses for this purpose typically).

The second method is to pass all of the data in a single message (whether a single stored procedure call, or in a single MSMQ message or whatever). The stored procedure (or whatever processes the message) can then allocate the unique identifier, perform all of the inserts, and return the allocated ID to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a client API that supports table-valued parameters, you can insert the Data row and related DataAttachments in a single round-trip using the technique in the example below.  In .NET, the TVP rows can be passed as DataTable, an array of DataRow, or an IEnumrable of type SqlDataRecord.  See http://www.dbdelta.com/maximizing-performance-with-table-valued-parameters/ for a sample C# code.

This technique can be extended to insert multiple Data rows too if you assign a key on the client side to correlate Data and DataAttachment rows.  You can then pass both as TVPs.  The correlation key would need to be column in both TVP types but not necessarily stored in the tables.

```
CREATE TYPE DataAttachmentType AS TABLE(
  [AttachmentType] [int] NOT NULL,
  [FileName] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [FileContent] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.InsertDataAndAttachments
    @IDDevice int
  , @Time datetime
  , @Value varchar(20)
  , @DataAttachments dbo.DataAttachmentType READONLY
AS
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

DECLARE @IDData int;

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRAN;

    INSERT  INTO dbo.Data
            ( IDDevice, Time, Value )
    VALUES  ( @IDDevice, @Time, @Value );

    SET @IDData = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT  INTO dbo.DataAttachment
            ( IDData
            , AttachmentType
            , FileName
            , FileContent
            )
            SELECT  @IDData
                  , AttachmentType
                  , FileName
                  , FileContent
            FROM    @DataAttachments;

    COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;

    THROW;

END CATCH;
GO
```